# Remove square brackets surrounding expression

Tags: replace

In Python, I am trying to update my code from typed dict to dataclass.
Language is just indicated as a reference, it is a pure Vim question.

I need to replace `my_params["some_property"]`  
with `my_params.some_property`

I have some difficulty replacing `["`.

How can I replace everything at once?

Answer (score 3):

Since replacing everything at once is likely to accidentally get some wrong things, I would make sure to add the `c`onfirm flag, or be a bit cleverer: we’ll use the [surround plugin](https://github.com/tpope/vim-surround) and a macro to step through the file and make the changes.

1. `/\["`: search for a pattern that should find all the things you need to change but may find extras. Press `n` until you’re on a match that needs changed.
2. `qqds[ds"i.<esc>q`: record a macro that deletes square brackets, quotes, and inserts a dot.
3. Press `n`/`N` to find places to edit and `@q` (the first time)/`@@` (subsequent times) to make the change.

Comment: Note that `ds` comes from this plugin: https://github.com/tpope/vim-surround - it's not "vanilla" Vim. (AFAIK anyway :) )

Comment: @Zoe you’re correct: I usually am too lazy to add links to well-known plugins from mobile and forget to add them in. Edits welcome in all such cases.

Comment: Oh, managed to miss the part where you said it was from a plugin. My bad!

Comment: @Zoe no worries :) thanks for making the link easy to add in!

Answer (score 2):

**New version from @b-layer**

```
:%s/\v\["([^"]+)"]/.\1/gc
```

- `%s` targets the whole file
- `\v` is the very magic modifier
- `\["` matches `["`
- `([^"]"+)` represents the capture group for `some_property`, which `[^"]` ends at the next double quotes. `+` makes it at least one character.
- `\1` references the capture group in the replacement section
- `\g` enables to replace for more than one occurrence per line and `c` asks for confirmation

**Previous version:**

I could perform the replacement executing the following command:

```
:%s/\v(\[")(.*)("\])/.\2/gc
```

where:

- `\v` is the very magic modifier,
- `(\[")`and `("\])` the capture groups 1 and 3 for the brackets and double quotes
- `(.*)` the capture group 2, which is then referenced with `\2` in the replacement section.

Comment: If you're not using them in the replacement you shouldn't need capture groups 1 and 3. Also,  `]` doesn't need to be escaped. Finally, `.*` is pretty greedy so it's usually safer to use a "not the next thing I want to match" pattern instead...in this case `[^"]*`.  So `:%s/\v\["([^"]*)"]/.\1/gc`

Comment: (And it really should be a `+` rather than a `*` since `my_params[""]` isn't valid...but that's a small detail. :)

Comment: thanks for the very thorough review :)

Answer (score 0):

Given I sometime use single quotes and other times doubles quotes, here is another variation on B-Layer `:substitute` command that supports both, plus the reverse operation.

In order to remember the names, I've wrapped the two actions into commands.

```
command! -range=1
      \ ToAttribute <line1>,<line2>s/\v\[(["'])([^"']+)\1]/.\2/gc
command! -range=1 -nargs=? -complete=customlist,s:compl_to_dict
      \ ToDict      call s:to_dict(<f-args>)


" Internal support functions for :ToDict
function! s:to_dict(...) range abort
  let quote = get(a:, 1, "'")
  exe printf('%s,%ss/\v\.(\k+)/[%s\1%s]/gc', a:firstline, a:lastline, quote, quote)
endfunction

function! s:compl_to_dict(...) abort
  return ['"', "'"]
endfunction
```